# Hello i need help for c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int edge, area, perimeter;

    printf("Lütfen karenin bir kenarını  giriniz ");
    scanf("%d", &edge);

    area= (edge*edge);
    perimeter= (edge*4);

    printf("Alanınız: %d \n", alan);
    printf("cevreniz: %d", perimeter);

    return(0);


}
```

Our teacher wants me to choose one of two shapes: square and rectangle and write a code to calculate the areas and perimeters of these shapes, can you help me? I'm sorry for my bad english

I don't know how to choose two different options

Answer (score 1):

here is an example, you need to implement a menu, this one is whit switch case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int opcion;

    printf("Menú\n");
    printf("1. Opción 1\n");
    printf("2. Opción 2\n");
    printf("Ingrese su opción: ");
    scanf("%d", &opcion);

    switch(opcion) {
        case 1:
            printf("Ha seleccionado la opción 1.\n");
            // Código para la opción 1
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Ha seleccionado la opción 2.\n");
            // Código para la opción 2
            break;
        default:
            printf("Opción inválida.\n");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BerkcanYemen The best way to thank people who helps you is to upvote their answers and if one answer sticks out, accept that answer.